# Bootcamp - Multiple Windows installations, how do delete one?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, hard-drive, hardware, performance

I've got a Mac Pro with 3 hard drives:

- 1 x 7200rpm 640GB - 1/2 for OS X - 1/2 for Windows 7 (Bootcamp)
- 2 x 5400 Western Digital'Eco-drive' (runs like a dog and is only useful for backups and archives).

In my foolishness I made two attempts to install (via Bootcamp) on the two slow drives before finally realising it was the slow speed of the drive that was making everything frustrating. So I now have OS X and Win7 on two halves of the 7200rpm drive and I'd like to get rid of the Win7 installs on the other drives. Somehow the installs ended up on partitions with other files so I can't just reformat them totally as I'd lose stuff.

I guess I could just delete the `Windows` folder from each location, but I don't think this will have the effect I'm after. Can anyone shed any light on what I should do?

Comment: Why deleting Windows folder doesn't help you? What effect are you after?

Comment: Bootcamp will still regard the partitions as bootable Windows ones after the Windows folders have been deleted. Must keep a setting somewhere...

Comment: What do you get? Do you see multiple Windows icons if you press Option during computer startup?

Comment: That sort of thing yes. The Bootcamp assistant version I use doesn't seem v. good at managing BC partitions not on the main OS X bootdrive.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the folders and files you need from the Windows partition(s) to your Mac partition, the do what @joelseph reccommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Disk Utility (/Applications/Utilities/) to erase the Western Digital drives.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please see edit above - the installs ended up on a non-blank partition so there are other folders on there along with the Windows and Users folder etc.